# axios frontend request always gets error from a Flask-restful backend, even when the response code is 200

Tags: reactjs, axios, flask-restful

I have the following **axios** post in a React application frontend:

```
import axios from "axios";
import { backendServer, getAuthHeader, getErrorMessage } from "./constants";

const connectPath = (host, port, database, user, password) => {
  const requestString = backendServer + 'connect/';
  const form = {
    host: host,
    port: port,
    database: database,
    user: user,
    password: password
  }
  
  return axios.post(requestString, form, getAuthHeader())
    .then((Response) => {
      return {
        connection: Response.data,
        message: null
      }
    })
    .catch((Error) => {
      return getErrorMessage(Error);
    })
}

export const paths = {
  connectPath,
}
```

And this **flask-restful** backend class:

```
class Connect(Resource):
    def post(self):
        
        try:
            data = json.loads(request.data)
        except:
            data = request.form
        
        connect(
            data['host'], 
            data['port'], 
            data['database'],
            data['user'],
            data['password']
        )
        
        return {'data': "ok"}

api.add_resource(Connect, '/connect/')
```

I can see that the frontend request is properly processed by the backend:

[image]

But, nevertheless, **axios** post always returns to `catch((Error))`.

I don't know hoy to make **axios** to go for the `then(Response)` when returning 200 from **flask-restful**.

**EDIT**

This is what I get in the `network` tab of the inspector:

[image]

Comment: What does the network request look like from the FE? You can see it in the network tab. Would be helpful to see that in your question

Comment: @topched I added it

Comment: There is no 200 OK in the response header so axios thinks its bad

Comment: @topched I know that, what I want to know is how can I make flask-restful to return a 200. I tried adding `, 200` after the return value, but nothing happened

Answer (score 1):

The solution was that I had to install and use `flask-cors`:

`pip install -U flask-cores`

```
import json
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_restful import Resource, Api
from flask_cors import CORS
from query import execute_query, connect

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app) # <<------- here
api = Api(app)
```